# Hyperledger: build chaincode using Gradle

Tags: gradle, hyperledger

I have problem when sending chaincode initialisation request using fabric-java-sdk.

Deploy(install) method:

```
public Collection<ProposalResponse> deploy(Collection<Peer> peers)
        throws InvalidArgumentException, ProposalException {

        String chaincodeName = chaincode.name();
        String chaincodeVersion = chaincode.version();

        HyperLedgerClient hyperLedgerClient = hyperLedgerChannelClient.getHyperLedgerClient();
        InstallProposalRequest request = hyperLedgerClient.newInstallProposalRequest();

        ChaincodeID.Builder chaincodeIDBuilder =
            ChaincodeID.newBuilder()
                .setName(chaincodeName)
                .setVersion(chaincodeVersion);

        ChaincodeID chaincodeID = chaincodeIDBuilder.build();

        LOGGER.info(
            "Deploying chaincode " + chaincodeName + " using Fabric client " +
                hyperLedgerClient.getUserContext().getMspId()
                + " " + hyperLedgerClient.getUserContext().getName()
        );

        request.setChaincodeID(chaincodeID);
        request.setUserContext(hyperLedgerClient.getUserContext());
        request.setChaincodeInputStream(chaincode.source());
        request.setChaincodeVersion(chaincodeVersion);
        request.setChaincodeLanguage(Type.JAVA);

        return hyperLedgerClient.sendInstallProposal(request, peers);
    }
```

Initialize(instantiate) method:

```
public Collection<ProposalResponse> instantiate(
        String functionName, String[] functionArgs)
        throws InvalidArgumentException, ProposalException {

        HyperLedgerClient hyperLedgerClient = hyperLedgerChannelClient.getHyperLedgerClient();

        String channelName = hyperLedgerChannelClient.getName();
        String chaincodeName = chaincode.name();

        String userContextName = hyperLedgerClient.getUserContext().getName();
        String mspId = hyperLedgerClient.getUserContext().getMspId();

        LOGGER.info(
            "Instantiate proposal request {} on channel {} with Fabric client {} {}",
            chaincodeName, channelName, mspId, userContextName
        );

        InstantiateProposalRequest instantiateProposalRequest =
            hyperLedgerClient.getHfClient().newInstantiationProposalRequest();

        instantiateProposalRequest.setProposalWaitTime(180000);
        ChaincodeID.Builder chaincodeIDBuilder = ChaincodeID.newBuilder()
            .setName(chaincodeName)
            .setVersion(chaincode.version());

        ChaincodeID ccid = chaincodeIDBuilder.build();
        LOGGER.info("Instantiating Chaincode ID {} on channel {}", chaincodeName, channelName);

        instantiateProposalRequest.setChaincodeID(ccid);
        instantiateProposalRequest.setChaincodeLanguage(Type.JAVA);
        instantiateProposalRequest.setFcn(functionName);
        instantiateProposalRequest.setArgs(functionArgs);
        Map<String, byte[]> tm = new HashMap<>();
        tm.put("HyperLedgerFabric", "InstantiateProposalRequest:JavaSDK".getBytes(UTF_8));
        tm.put("method", "InstantiateProposalRequest".getBytes(UTF_8));
        instantiateProposalRequest.setTransientMap(tm);

        Collection<ProposalResponse> responses =
            hyperLedgerChannelClient.sendInstantiationProposal(instantiateProposalRequest);

        CompletableFuture<TransactionEvent> completableFuture =
            hyperLedgerChannelClient.sendTransaction(responses);

        LOGGER.info(
            "Chaincode {} on channel {} instantiation {}",
            chaincodeName, channelName, completableFuture
        );

        return responses;
    }
```

chaincode.source() points to .tgz file which has the following content

```
➜ transfer-chaincode git:(master) ✗ gradle clean buildProjectArchive 
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
➜ transfer-chaincode git:(master) ✗ tar -tvf build/distributions/transfer-chaincode-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.tgz
-rw-r--r-- 0 0 0 1817 Mar 2 21:31 build.gradle
drwxr-xr-x 0 0 0 0 Feb 25 15:00 src/
drwxr-xr-x 0 0 0 0 Mar 2 21:22 src/main/
drwxr-xr-x 0 0 0 0 Mar 2 18:50 src/main/resources/
drwxr-xr-x 0 0 0 0 Mar 2 18:50 src/main/resources/config/
-rw-r--r-- 0 0 0 0 Mar 2 18:50 src/main/resources/config/application.yml
drwxr-xr-x 0 0 0 0 Feb 25 15:02 src/main/java/
drwxr-xr-x 0 0 0 0 Feb 25 15:02 src/main/java/com/
drwxr-xr-x 0 0 0 0 Feb 25 15:02 src/main/java/com/
drwxr-xr-x 0 0 0 0 Feb 25 15:02 src/main/java/com/fundtransfer/
drwxr-xr-x 0 0 0 0 Mar 2 18:49 src/main/java/com/fundtransfer/transfer/
-rw-r--r-- 0 0 0 1142 Mar 2 18:49 src/main/java/com/fundtransfer/transfer/TransferChaincodeApplication.java
drwxr-xr-x 0 0 0 0 Mar 2 21:12 src/main/java/com/fundtransfer/transfer/service/
-rw-r--r-- 0 0 0 1950 Mar 2 21:12 src/main/java/com/fundtransfer/transfer/service/ChaincodeEntrypoint.java
drwxr-xr-x 0 0 0 0 Mar 2 21:23 src/main/gradle/
-rw-r--r-- 0 0 0 39 Mar 2 21:23 src/main/gradle/settings.gradle
-rw-r--r-- 0 0 0 1587 Mar 2 21:28 gradle.properties
-rw-r--r-- 0 0 0 39 Mar 2 21:23 settings.gradle
```

Peer docker-compose configuration:

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

services:
    peer-base:
        image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:$HYPERLEDGER_VERSION
        environment:
            - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
            # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
            # bridge network as the peers
            # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
            - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_fundtransfer
#            - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
            - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
            - CORE_PEER_ENDORSER_ENABLED=true
            - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
            - CORE_PEER_CHANNELSERVICE_ENABLED=true
            - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
            - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
            - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=false
            - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.crt
            - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/server.key
            - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls/ca.crt
        working_dir: /opt/hyperledger/peer
        command: peer node start
```

Peer logs:

```
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | 2019-03-02 17:39:27.230 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 1ad unary call completed {"grpc.start_time": "2019-03-02T17:39:27.194Z", "grpc.service": "protos.Endorser", "grpc.method": "ProcessProposal", "grpc.peer_address": "172.20.0.1:41564", "grpc.code": "OK", "grpc.call_duration": "35.5921ms"}
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | 2019-03-02 17:39:32.846 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 1ae [all-orgs-channel][ada2da1f] Entry chaincode: name:"lscc"
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | 2019-03-02 17:39:58.340 UTC [chaincode.platform.java] GenerateDockerBuild -> ERRO 1af Can't build java chaincode Error returned from build: 1 "Maven build
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] Total time: 1.818 s
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-02T17:39:57Z
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] Final Memory: 6M/46M
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/chaincode/input/src). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR]
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR]
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | "
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | 2019-03-02 17:39:58.340 UTC [chaincode.platform] func1 -> ERRO 1b0 Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "Maven build
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] Total time: 1.818 s
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-02T17:39:57Z
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] Final Memory: 6M/46M
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/chaincode/input/src). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR]
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR]
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | "
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | 2019-03-02 17:39:58.340 UTC [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 1b1 Error building image: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "Maven build
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] Total time: 1.818 s
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-02T17:39:57Z
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] Final Memory: 6M/46M
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/chaincode/input/src). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR]
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR]
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | "
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | 2019-03-02 17:39:58.340 UTC [dockercontroller] deployImage -> ERRO 1b2 Build Output:
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | ********************
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  |
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | ********************
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | 2019-03-02 17:39:58.359 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 1b3 [all-orgs-channel][ada2da1f] Exit chaincode: name:"lscc"  (25548ms)
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | 2019-03-02 17:39:58.359 UTC [endorser] SimulateProposal -> ERRO 1b4 [all-orgs-channel][ada2da1f] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "Maven build
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] Total time: 1.818 s
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-02T17:39:57Z
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] Final Memory: 6M/46M
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/chaincode/input/src). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR]
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR]
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | "
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | error starting container
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | error starting container
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | 2019-03-02 17:39:58.359 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 1b5 unary call completed {"grpc.start_time": "2019-03-02T17:39:32.845Z", "grpc.service": "protos.Endorser", "grpc.method": "ProcessProposal", "grpc.peer_address": "172.20.0.1:41564", "grpc.code": "OK", "grpc.call_duration": "25.5488994s"}
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | 2019-03-02 17:47:34.631 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 1b6 [all-orgs-channel][74212e9f] Entry chaincode: name:"lscc"
    peer0.gateway.fundtransfer.com                  | 2019-03-02 17:47:36.258 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 1b7 streaming call completed {"grpc.start_time": "2019-03-02T17:39:18.839Z", "grpc.service": "protos.Deliver", "grpc.method": "Deliver", "grpc.peer_address": "172.20.0.1:41566", "error": "context finished before block retrieved: context canceled", "grpc.code": "Unknown", "grpc.call_duration": "8m18.0064816s"}
```

The problem is that I am using `gradle`. How can I switch my peers to use gradle?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in that I was sending `tgz`archive with the following structure inside:

```
src/main/...
build.gradle
settings.gradle
```

But I was needed to change it to:

```
src/src/main/...
src/build.gradle
src/settings.gradle
```

Then peers will recognise Gradle.